# In-App purchase sometimes fails with SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown Error." in production

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, storekit, mac-app-store

I have a Mac app that offers an In-App purchase. Once in a while I have users contacting me, because purchasing fails with the error below.

Please note that this happens for regular users. It works fine for me. (There are many questions on SO where this happens for developers with "test" user accounts, this is not the case here).

Error:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown Error." UserInfo=0x7fead1e44490 
{NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Error.}
```

Comment: I think in development or for real users, it's the same "pain". After having worked with StoreKit for a few months, I think I can resume it by "yet another technology I will never ever use again". Seems as awesome as iCloud sync :( Or did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Operation could not be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)” in the production environment, try the following: Make sure you have used the correct `Product Identifier`. If you have, after you call `[SKPaymentQueue addPayment:]`, you will receive error 0 before you are asked to confirm payment. Create a new test user if your current test user has been invalidated. If you accidentally log in to the App Store with your test user, you will receive error 0 after entering your password to confirm the payment.

Unfortunately, there is nothing else that can be done about this error while in the production environment. This error is mainly caused by Apple, and it is an unknown error related to their API. When the issue is on Apple’s side, it's always a good idea to submit a bug report with complete information, including a sysdiagnose archive from the device.